# SED command not working in perl script

Tags: perl, unix

When i am using  "sed" in command line it is working but not when included in perl script.

An example is   **sed 's/\s+//g' aaa > bbb**

but say when i am trying to call the same command through perl script

```
$gf = `sed 's/\s\+//g' aaa > bbb` ;
```

the output file remains same as the input file!!!! Please suggest.

Comment: Can you give a complete example including the perl script and values of variable `aaa` - exactly how it is entered? You know that `\s+` is not the same as `\s\+`, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918128/how-can-i-do-bulk-search-and-replace-with-perl

Comment: thanks..i think the following answer given  below is what i was looking for..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, backticks have the same escape and interpolation rules as double quoted strings: A backslash forming an unknown escape code forgets the backslash, e.g. `"\." eq "."`.

Therefore, the Perl code

```
print `echo \"1\"`;
print `echo \\"1\\"`;
```

outputs

```
1
"1"
```

If you want to embed that `sed` command into Perl, you have to escape the backslashes so that they even reach the `sh`ell:

```
$gf = `sed 's/\\s\\+//g' aaa > bbb`;
```

Actually, you won't get any output into `$gf` as you redirect the output to a file. We could just do

```
use autodie;

system "sed 's/\\s\\+//g' aaa > bbb";
```

or with single quotes:

```
use autodie;

system q{ sed 's/\s\+//g' aaa > bbb };
```

which keeps the backslashes.

Still, this is quite unneccessary as Perl could apply the substitution itself.

```
use autodie; # automatic error handling

open my $out, ">", "bbb";
open my $in,  "<", "aaa";
while (<$in>) {
  s/\s\+//g; # remove all spaces followed by a plus
  print {$out} $_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot amon.... i had wasted more that 3 hours on this and you have solved this issue in 1 min. Thanks alot alot

Comment: Did you mean `sed sed` or did a typo sneak in? If not a typo, can you explain why two `sed`s in a row? Apart from that very nice and clear solution!

Comment: @Floris Thanks for spotting the duplicates.

Comment: This is quite helpful for dealing with situations where GNU sed is required and you might be deploying to a platform that has, say, BSD sed.

Answer (score 0):

In these weird situations, I ensure that I'm running the right command. I'll construct it, store it, and output the command so I can see exactly what I created:

```
my $command = '....';
print "Command is [$command]\n";
my $output = `$command`;
```

If you're running `sed` from Perl, you might be doing it wrong since Perl can already do all that.

Answer (score -2):

have you got

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
```

at the top of your file?

you could need backticks to execute the command

```
  $gf = `sed 's/\s\+//g' aaa > bbb`;
```